# Selection in a small category

Tags: ct.category-theory, axiom-of-choice

I came across the following problem. I do not know if these notions are known (I would actually be interested to know), so the names might not be the canonical ones.

Given a small category $C$, a **partial selection** $S$ of $C$ is a category of the following form:

1. The set of objects of $S$ is a subset of the objects of $C$.
2. For every pair $s$ and $s’$ of objects of $S$, $S$ has at most one morphism from $s$ to $s’$, and this potential morphism is a morphism of $C$ from $s$ to $s’$. Furthermore, there is a morphism from $s$ to $s’$ in $S$ if and only if there is one in $C$. Denote this morphism by $f(S,s,s’)$, when it exists.
3. The identity of $s$ in $S$ is the identity of $s$ in $C$, which means that $f(S,s,s)$ exists and is $id_s$.
4. The composition of $S$ is the composition in $C$, which means that if $f(S,s’,s’’)$ and $f(S,s,s’)$ exist then $f(S,s,s’’)$ exists and is equal to $f(S,s’,s’’)\circ f(S,s,s’)$.

In particular, a partial selection is a subcategory of $C$ which is a preordered set.

We say that a partial selection $S$ is **total** if $S$ is a wide subcategory of $C$, that is, its set of objects is precisely the set of objects of $C$. So, a total selection is a way to pick exactly one morphism in every non-empty Hom-set of $C$, while being compatible with the category structure. It is a kind of ``categorical choice''.

Obviously, there are categories which do not have total selections. For example, consider $C$ the free category generated by $\text{Obj} = \{a,b,c,d\}$, $\text{Mor}_{a,b} = \{f\}$, $\text{Mor}_{b,d} = \{g\}$, $\text{Mor}_{a,c}=\{h\}$ and $\text{Mor}_{c,d} = \{k\}$. A total selection of $C$ must contain $\{f,g,h,k\}$, and so must also contain $g\circ f$ and $k\circ h$, which are different.

I would be interested in proving that some categories have a total selection, but I cannot figure out which properties make a category have a selection. Would you see some simple necessary conditions for a category to have a selection?

Comment: You probably know this, but:  Given a set $A$ (and given the axiom of choice), the category of all subsets of $A$ has a total selection:  First well-order $A$, and then let the unique map from $s$ to $s'$ take all of $s$ to the smallest element of $s'$ (assuming of course that $s'$ is nonempty).

Comment: Yes, that is a good observation. There are many examples of total selections involving the axiom of choice in sets, which is to be expected.